# Overwrite / update browser cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, web, browser

I have an Express 4.x app, and I pass a cookie to the browser with

```
res.cookie('foo','bar1', {maxAge:99999999999});
```

it expires in the distant future. However, 5 minutes later, I get another request from the same user, and I want to give them a new cookie.

```
 res.cookie('foo','bar2', {maxAge:99999999999});
```

From my debugging, it looks like the new cookie doesn't overwrite the old cookie? Is that the case? **How can I update/overwrite the old cookie with the new one?**

Comment: It looks like from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies

Comment: that I should use { overwrite: true }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am about 99% certain that using the `{overwrite: true}` property will do the trick - from here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies

it says:

> cookies.set( name, [ value ], [ options ] ) This sets the given cookie
>   in the response and returns the current context to allow chaining.
>
> If the value is omitted, an outbound header with an expired date is
>   used to delete the cookie.
>
> If the options object is provided, it will be used to generate the
>   outbound cookie header as follows:
>
> maxAge: a number representing the milliseconds from Date.now() for
>   expiry expires: a Date object indicating the cookie's expiration date
>   (expires at the end of session by default). ... overwrite: a boolean
>   indicating whether to overwrite previously set cookies of the same
>   name (false by default). If this is true, all cookies set during the
>   same request with the same name (regardless of path or domain) are
>   filtered out of the Set-Cookie header when setting this cookie.

So that would be, in Node.js Express parlance:

```
res.cookie('cdt_app_token', encoded, {maxAge: 90000000, httpOnly: true, secure: false, overwrite: true});
```

*Note that if you are using a non SSL or non TLS connection, cookies may not work if secure is true.*

Comment: I think the OP talks about https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie and you refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies. Looking at Express docs, there is no 'overwrite' attribute, seems to be unique to the library you refer to.

Comment: I just discovered the same: In Express there is no overwrite option, at least the TypeScript Interface and the API docs say so. So what is the solution with Express only?