# how to update a cookie using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I set cookie using the below code,

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let options = {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15, // would expire after 15 minutes
    httpOnly: true, // The cookie only accessible by the web server
  };

  let userData = {
    name: "John",
    age: 23,
  };

  // Set cookie
  res.cookie("cookieName", userData, options); // options is optional
  res.send("done");
});
```

Read the cookie using,

```
app.get("/get", function (req, res) {
  // read cookies
  res.send(req.cookies["cookieName"]);
});
```

I need to update the value in the cookie, need to change age:23 to age:32. How can I update the cookie?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401785/overwrite-update-browser-cookie) should answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
let userData = {
    name: "John",
    age: 32,
  };      
res.cookie("cookieName", userData, options); // options is optional
```

same code will work for update part, if key name is same, if key name is different it'll create new key in cookie